# Зависает таймер Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Функция

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   timer_update.Interval = IntervalUpdate;
   timer_update.Tick += new EventHandler(MainForm_Load);
   timer_update.Enabled = true;
}
```

После 7-8 срабатываний таймера в диспетчере задач не отвечает и начинает жрать процессор.
Как можно избежать этого или каким другим способом осуществить регулярное обновление функции MainForm_Load?

Comment: Ааааа! Рекурсивная бомба! Все в укрытие!

Comment: красава, посмеялся

Comment: А что вы пытались сделать?

Comment: в функции MainForm_Load у меня стоит обработка программы(Обработка запроса на сервер и вывод всей необходимой инфы). И надо чтоб функция перезапускалась. я так понял, что в тик добавление евента происходит добавлением +=, но и это начинает перегружать программу.

Answer (score 3):

**1. "Не путайте теплое с мягким"**

Первая и главная ошибка - вы пытаетесь всю логику программы впихнуть в обработчики событий. Этого делать не нужно, потому что если потребуется чуть-чуть изменить логику - придется лезть в код визуальных компонентов и т.д. и т.п. со всей вытекающей головной болью.

Код обработчиков событий должен быть максимально кратким и простым, т.к. событий и обработчиков обычно довольно много и в них легко запутаться. Особенно если куски кода просто копипастятся из обработчика в обработчик.

**2. Разделяем модель и представление**

В простейшем случае, достаточно создать отдельный класс или набор классов, для хранения и обработки данных. Назовем этот класс условно `MyModel`. В этом классе определяете поля для хранения данных и метод для их загрузки, например
`public void LoadData()` в котором производите все необходимые действия для получения данных. Также определяете в данном классе свойства для контролируемого доступа к данным и передачи их визуальным компонентам для отображения и, возможно, модификации.

**3. Как это выглядит и как этим пользоваться?**

Определяем модель

```
public class MyModel
{
     public int MyData1 { get; private set; }//свойство только для чтения
     public string MyData2 { get; set; }//свойство для чтения и записи
     ...
     //остальные нужные свойства
     ...
     public void LoadData()
     {
         MyData1 = 100500;//замените на вашу логику получения данных
         MyData2 = "I'm cool string";
     }
     ...
     //остальная логика работы с данными модели
}
```

теперь в форме

```
public class MainForm : Form
{
    private MyModel model;//форма должна знать что у нее есть модель,
                          //поэтому размещаем ссылку на нашу модель

    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Инициализируем модель и загружаем данные
        model = new MyModel();
        model.LoadData();
        //Настраиваем таймер
        timer_update.Interval = IntervalUpdate;
        timer_update.Tick += new EventHandler(TickHandler);
        timer_update.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void TickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        model.LoadData();
    }
    //далее все остальное что там нужно
}
```

Уже заметили разницу? Даже если вам понадобится изменить логику загрузки данных, вы будете делать это в одном единственном месте и не страдать от ошибок копипаста. Если понадобиться поменять визуальные компоненты - это опять же ни как не скажется на модели.

Пример сильно упрощен, и далеко не идеален, хотя для приложения с одной основной формой вполне пригоден. Более подробно читайте в литературе по шаблонам проектирования (disign patterns), например **[тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns)** для начала. Применительно к WinForms ближе всего MVP (Model-View-Presenter) или MVPVM, но последний сложнее и не всегда в нем есть реальная необходимость, но ознакомиться, хотя бы поверхностно, рекомендую со всеми паттернами и анти-паттернами, чтобы иметь базовое представление о том как, когда и зачем они применяются, если даже в чем то не разберетесь сразу - это не страшно, понимание придет со временем и опытом, ну или зададите еще один вопрос тут =)

Answer (score 2):

Не нужно использовать метод MainForm_Load в качестве обработчика события Tick, после каждого тика это метод будет вызываться и создавать нового подписчика для события Tick - опять метод MainForm_Load. Это вызывает бесконечную рекурсию и неограниченное добавление обработчиков на событие Tick - после первого Tick кол-во обработчиков - 2, после второго - 4 и т.д. пока не закончится память.
  Нужно создать метод который должен выполняться на каждый Tick, в этом методе не должен создаваться подписчик события Tick.
  Например ваш код можно изменить следующим образом:

```
`//Этот метод должен вызываться один раз! чтобы не создавать ненужных подписчиков на событие Tick
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer_update.Interval = IntervalUpdate;
    timer_update.Tick += new EventHandler(TickHandler); //здесь TickHandler, а не MainForm_Load
    timer_update.Enabled = true;
}
private void TickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Логика по обработке события Tick
}`
```

Comment: но в таком случае при первой загрузке ничего не произойдет, пока таймер не начнет исполняться. А если я поставлю таймер в 300 секунд, то первые пять минут ничего не выполнится.

Comment: при первой загрузке, если необходимо, можно просто вызвать метод TickHandler.

Comment: Либо при создании Timer можно указать initial delay - 0, тогда обработчик Tick вызовется сразу после запуска таймера, параметр называется dueTime в конструкторе Timer

Comment: А вот так можно?

    LoadProgramm(sender, e);
            timer_update.Interval = IntervalUpdate;
            timer_update.Tick += new EventHandler(LoadProgramm);
            timer_update.Enabled = true;