# Менять значения между панелями в C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Привет. Не доходит как поменять значения между двумя панелями во время выполнения программы.
Есть форма(WindowsForms), есть два панели(П1 и П2, П1 видно а П2 скрытая) на которых 2 списка(ListBox).
В программе при старте видно П1, пополняем список, потом при нажатии на кнопку, П1 должна скрытся(Hide) и П2 появится(Show). При этом обмене на П2 нужно передать данные из П1. Это все на форме.

Практически это можно представить как добавление контакта. Добавляешь все данные контакта на первую панель, а на второй панели уже появляется вся информация о контакте.

Обновлено(17.03.2017):
Так вот...кнопка которая "меняет" панели была на одной из панели и она должна была проделать всю работу по обмену. Сделал костыль: поставил кнопку в глобальную зону(т.е. на самой форме), теперь есть глобальный доступ к одним и тем же данным, у обеих панелей. Если есть другие предложения, буду благодарен.

Comment: почитайте, большей частью ответ подходит и к вашему вопросу http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/570031/198316 Если принципиально менять ни чего не хочется, приведите пример вашего кода, в котором возникла ошибка, без этого даже "костыль" предложить сложно, потому что по вашему описанию можно соорудить десяток разных вариантов решения одно другого "краше"

Comment: Вы ведь сами рассказали только что всю логику программы, в чем конкретно возникли затруднения ? В реализации в виде кода ?

Comment: Так как обе панели у меня прописаны в форме, не понимаю как из одной панели работать с данными другой панели. Нужно как-то сделать чтобы все данные были глобальными(т.е. видны для П1 и П2), сейчас только П1 видит (свои) данные.

Comment: @Romeon0 "Нужно как-то сделать чтобы все данные были глобальными" - и да и нет. нет - никаких специальных открытых полей в контролах, каждый контрол работает со своими данными и не лезет в чужие. Да - для данных нужно определить набор классов, который описывает сами данные, связи между ними, логику. Ссылку на нужный класс из этого набора положить в контрол. Почитайте первую ссылку, там даже пример есть.

Answer (score 1):

Так вот...кнопка которая "меняет" панели была на одной из панели и она должна была проделать всю работу по обмену. Сделал костыль: поставил кнопку в глобальную зону(т.е. на самой форме), теперь есть глобальный доступ к одним и тем же данным, у обеих панелей. Если есть другие предложения, буду благодарен.